# mysqli select where in

Tags: mysqli

подскажите как формировать stmt запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN()
```

в IN должна подставляться строка вида "1,2,3,4,5,6"
я уже перепробовал все варианты какие смог придумать
вот последний:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".substr(str_repeat('?,',count($params) ), 0, -1 .")"  

$params=explode(",", "1,2,3,4,5,6");  
$types=array(substr(str_repeat('i,',count($params), 0, -1 ));  

call_user_func_array(array($query,"bind_param"), array_merge($types,$params));//line 185  
$query->execute();
$result=$query->get_result();
```

и все равно получаю

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in D:\server\www\ajax.php on line 185
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703264/6104996  |  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968269/6104996

Comment: в этом случае получаю   Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in D:\server\www\ajax.php on line 188

Comment: ты на древней PHP работаешь?  если ниже 5.3 тогда сюда обходной путь http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96770  (в комментариях к ответу было написано кстати)

Comment: версия 5.6.30.... .. .

Comment: и этот массив со ссылками я тоже сделал. только что за $this->stmt я не понял

Comment: спасибо, проблема решена. так и чувствовал что где то запятую не там поставил, или еще что то